# how do you run parallel code on Win10 terminal

Tags: python, terminal, windows-10, mpi

In lessons we've been creating and running parallel programs on a virtual machine running Linux and we've been running python programs directly though the terminal with the command line

```
mpi4exec -n N python my_file.py
```

when we moved to a mac suit we had to run the command line

```
export PATH=/Users/admin/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

first before mpi4exec was a recognised commmand. After this the file would run fine.

My question is firstly, what does the mac line actually mean/do and secondly, is there a Win10 equivalent that allows me to run python code directly though my PC terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can run python code same as that of linux in temrinal/command prompt. 
for this you have to set the python path to the window environmental variable path by yourself or you can install the anaconda which do everything, install python, python-packages, spyder ide .

Comment: so i have anaconda installed and am using spyder, so do i need to set up the path with spyder as the goal then?

Comment: While installing anaconda it ask for setup the path by itself at begining . If you have chosen that then you don't need to setup the path . Other wise you need to add python path to the variable environment to run through termainl .  In pycharm you can also give python path ( anaconda python ) to run your project.